# Create outlines for text in an inserted object in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is there any way to create outlines for text that is included in an inserted object?
When I "select all" and create outlines, and export the document to pdf, I can see that the text that was included in the figures (in my case, copied and pasted from an illustrator file) is not outlined and is still editable.

What I'm doing is reopening the pdf file with Illustrator and creating outlines for this text that is still editable, but I'm pretty sure there should be a way to do it all from indesign, and no need to spend time reopening in Illustrator.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not think InDesign can outline text from linked or embedded files. You could use Acrobat to outline all text after you're done and export your PDF.

Comment: What _is_ the “inserted object”? Is it a placed file? Something copy-pasted from another ID document? Something else?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet placed object i presume

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The inserted object is a figure with some text indications, copied and pasted from illustrator.

Comment: @Capiedge In that case, just create outlines in Illustrator before you copy-paste, and then undo to get your editable text back. It’s one extra step, but a tiny one.

Comment: @AndrewH Yes, I know that I can do this from Acrobat, but I'm trying to find a way to avoid this step, creating outlines from Indesign.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,  yes, that's right, I was trying to find a way to avoid this extra step.

Comment: The only extra step is that, while in Illustrator (after you’ve outlined), instead of hitting Ctrl/Cmd+C, you hit Ctrl/Cmd+C, then Ctrl/Cmd+Z. It’ll take about half a second extra.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, the problem comes when you realize that, and you have dozens of figures already pasted in your indesign document. In that case it's more than half a second extra. But, thanks anyway ;-)